# What does "SEM1:3ENCE_B:NW:NG102:EECT300:120:0900:2" mean?

Tags: text

In my project I am developing teachers and their timetable. I was provided with a [text](http://codebin.org/view/ba6d7085) file that contains the teacher timetable from my uni. They ware unable to tell me what is the syntax or code language so I would know how to read it and use it in my iPhone app. Can you help me identifying what sot of code is this and how can I read that?

Sample:

```
SEM1:3ENCE_B:NW:NG102:EECT300:120:0900:2
SEM1:3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C:TW:NLG107:EEEL300:120:0900:1
19:3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C:TW:CLG.01:EEEL305_L:120:1100:1
19:3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C:TW:NLG107:EEEL305:120:0900:1
SEM1:3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B:TW::EEEL300:120:1100:4
SEM1&2:3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C,3ENCE_D:SK:CLG.06:EEEL315_L:120:1400:4
SEM1:3CS_A,3CS_B,3CS_C,3CS_D,3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C,3ENCE_D:DHE:CLLT:EICG301_L:120:0900:5
SEM1:3CS_A,3CS_B:ABO,DHE:N5.114:EICG301:120:1100:5
SEM1:3CS_A,3CS_B,3CS_C,3CS_D,3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C,3ENCE_D:NW:LTS205:EECT300_L:120:1600:2
27:3ENCE_A,3ENCE_B,3ENCE_C,3ENCE_CS::NG100:EEEL320:120:1100:2
SEM1:3CS_A,3CS_B,3CS_C,3CS_D:NW:C2.14:ECSC302_L:120:0900:3
SEM1:3CS_A:NW:NG100:EECT300:120:1400:2
```

Comment: This is no code, this is just a file that references objects. Values of these objects are seperated by `:`.

Comment: It looks like a database dump.  It looks like several tables with different formats were all dumped in one text file.  I'm guessing SEM1 is first semester and SEM2 is second semester.  My suggestion would be to go through the dump and identify the different types of line layouts.  At least you'd have an idea of how many tables were involved.  Then you can work on deciphering each type into columns.

Answer (score 2):

It's not code, it's data. And the best way of interpreting it is to compare this representation with another : Think [Rosetta Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone).

Obviously, colon is used to separate the fields, and each line probably represents a single tinmetable item. Each line appears to have 8 fields on it.

One field looks like a course ID : [EECT300](https://sites.google.com/a/staff.westminster.ac.uk/eect300/)

Another looks like a time : 0900

As for the rest, you'll have to work it out...

University of Westminster, maybe...?

Comment: I have done further research which leads to the rosettacode.org. This file is following sort of rosetta character algorithm or actually Evolutionary algorithm. If I am right, there is a lot to learn. However, thank you for ideas and yes its westminster.

Comment: @PurpleMonk : I wasn't referring to rosettacode or any website: Just the concept that if you already have a 'translation' of the data (like last terms timetable, printed or on a website) it will help you understand what the data fields could mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a code language.

It is just a plain text file which contains data using colons `:` as a separator

I guess you have to parse it and retrieve the information for each column. You have to be aware of the signification of each column (if no ask to your uni)